# How to detect changes to disk capacity in linux?

Tags: linux, disk, block-device

I'm working on a program that needs to monitor changes to the system mounts and the size of disks and partitions. While I found out the changes in mounts can be detected using `epoll` on `/proc/mounts`, is there an efficient way to detect size changes in disks?

- I already tried using `epoll` on `/proc/partitions`, but that didn't help.
- I also noticed that some messages are generated in the kernel ring buffer when I change the disk size (see below). Monitoring the buffer for these messages may also work, but I would like to know if there are any other methods to solve this issue.

```
[1883313.043332] sd 2:0:0:1: Capacity data has changed
[1883313.045638] sd 2:0:0:1: [sda] 1077936128 512-byte logical blocks: (552 GB/514 GiB)
[1883313.046073] sda: detected capacity change from 550829555712 to 551903297536
```